OSpanel 6 set up nginx config
How in OSpanel 6 set up nginx config? There is not a word about this in documentation.
I tried create a config in project direction or project > .osp direction. Replace config in modules > nginx > conf doesn`t work too.

I found a solution, all just need to do is create [your_domen_name].conf in your_project > .osp > nginx. Body config must be like that:
    location / {
                ...
   }

   location ^~ /api/ {
                ...
   }

